# bitcoin address from xpub key

Tags: public-key, address-generation, bitcore

I want to create bitcoin address from extended public key, without exposing private key but did not get any success till now. Do someone know how to do it? I am using bitcore-lib package

Comment: can you provide any code and the problems you're having?

Answer (score 2):

According to BIP32 you're trying to generate a non-hardened child address, see [BIP32 - Public parent key → public child key](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#public-parent-key--public-child-key).

Using bitcore-lib, to derive a non-hardened child public key and a P2PKH address:

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');
var Address = bitcore.Address;
var PublicKey = bitcore.PublicKey;
var Networks = bitcore.Networks;

var hdPublickey = new bitcore.HDPublicKey('tpubD6NzVbkrYhZ4XLMmry7XriYJ6Xgx1vQqoUZHLUXQPDB32n7pQYaWSMpRttm2sHzYjsQqrsAZYyJCmoEJB51oSdqZxq7epGjP4vHriCYz7Tp');
var orderPublickey = hdPublickey.deriveChild("m/44/145/0/0");
var pubkey = new PublicKey(orderPublickey.publicKey);
var address = Address.fromPublicKey(pubkey, Networks.testnet);
console.log("address", address);
```

Returns:
`address <Address: mkVBk6gZ7rBLYXvpdcKwTEq6SjHvSeLwZ8, type: pubkeyhash, network: testnet>`

Comment: could we convert  this publicKey into bitcoin base58 address?

Comment: I got this method bitcore.Address.fromPublicKey() but it is not working

Comment: What is it doing? Also, try `var address = Address(publicKey, 'mainnet').toString();` Also it depends on what type of address you want (`p2sh` or `p2pkh`)

Comment: please define Address? do you have any working code that can generate bitcoin address from xpub?

Comment: Have you tried the above? Is it not working for you?

Comment: i have tried lots of time in addr = Address(publicKey, 'mainnet').toString(), i am trying to figure out how to define Address??

Comment: see my edit above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80609/discussion-between-jbaczuk-and-rahul-saini).

Comment: hii @JBaczuk i inboxed you

Comment: How can i get the privatekey for the above adddress mkVBk6gZ7rBLYXvpdcKwTEq6SjHvSeLwZ8

Comment: @IshwarChandra you can't. If you could, then how would you ever hold Bitcoin without someone computing your private key and stealing your funds?

Comment: @JBaczuk yeah i know .you are right.....

Comment: @JBaczuk today i exported xpub from coinomi and used in the above code to generate bitcoin address and sent bitcoin.... now my problem is how can i get the fund i sent to that new bitcoin address, which is not in my coinomi wallet and even i did not get any notification incoming transaction on my coinomi wallet

Comment: @IshwarChandra doing that is most likely is not supported by their application. Hopefully you can export your private key from coinomi, then you'll have to figure out how to sign a transaction with that key and send it back to an address in one of your wallet applications.

Comment: @JBaczuk thanks, my requirement is if someone sharing me his xpub from exodus or any xpub supported wallet and i am creating bitcoin address using that xpub so is there any way like he can manage those funds. I mean, I will only generate the addresses using xpub and the one who is having xpub, xpriv and its mnemonic he can access/use that funds.

Comment: @IshwarChandra There are ways, but I don't know if there are any wallets that would support what you want out of the box. You might have to create your own.